# Solve recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence. First transform it to a simpler recurrence and then solve
the new recurrence using generating functions or a characteristic polynomial:
$f_n = f_{n−1} · f_{n−2}$ for $n \ge  2, f_0 = 2, f_1 = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Define $g_n = \log_2 f_n$.

---

Adding details:  The substitution above gives the linear homogeneous recurrence relation
$$g_0 = 1,\; g_1 = 2,\; n \ge 1 \implies g_n = g_{n-1}+g_{n-2}$$

This should remind you of the Fibonacci recurrence.  As you have noted, the characteristic equation and roots are:
$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1 = 0, \quad \lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1\pm \sqrt5}2,$$
so the solution must be of form $g_n = c_1 \lambda_1^n+c_2\lambda_2^n$.  Using the initial conditions, we need 
$$g_0 = 1 = c_1+c_2, \; g_1 =2 = \frac12 (1+\sqrt5 ) c_1+\frac12 (1-\sqrt5) c_2$$

Solving that gives you for the coefficients
$$c_{1,2} = \frac{5\pm3\sqrt5}{10}$$
So we have in general
$$g_n = \frac{\left(5-3 \sqrt{5}\right) \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^n+\left(5+3 \sqrt{5}\right) \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^n}{5\cdot 2^{n+1}}$$

and $f_n = 2^{g_n}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21501/discussion-between-macavity-and-user2057890).

Comment: Given that you haven't joined a chat, I have added details in the post itself rather than continue this chain of comments.  Hope that will help.